# Function call taking place automatically in n-queen problem

Tags: c++, function, recursion, call, n-queens

I found this code to find all the possible solutions of an n-queen problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int board[20], count;

int main()
{
    int n, i, j;
    void queen(int row, int n);

    printf(" - N Queens Problem Using Backtracking -");
    printf("\n\nEnter number of Queens:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    queen(1, n);
    return 0;
}

//function for printing the solution
void print(int n)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("\n\nSolution %d:\n\n", ++count);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        printf("\t%d", i);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        printf("\n\n%d", i);
        for (j = 1; j <= n; ++j) //for nxn board
        {
            if (board[i] == j)
                printf("\tQ"); //queen at i,j position
            else
                printf("\t-"); //empty slot
        }
    }


}

/*funtion to check conflicts
If no conflict for desired postion returns 1 otherwise returns 0*/
int place(int row, int column)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= row - 1; ++i)
    {
        //checking column and digonal conflicts
        if (board[i] == column)
            return 0;
        else
            if (abs(board[i] - column) == abs(i - row))
                return 0;
    }

    return 1; //no conflicts
}

//function to check for proper positioning of queen
void queen(int row, int n)
{
    int column;
    for (column = 1; column <= n; ++column)
    {
        if (place(row, column))
        {
            board[row] = column; //no conflicts so place queen
            if (row == n) //dead end
                print(n); //printing the board configuration
            else //try queen with next position
                queen(row + 1, n);
        }
    }
}
```

My confusion is that the main() function calls the function queen() just one time, but when the for loop of the queen() function ends, the queen() function starts again. I saw it by debugging that when the value column in for loop reaches its max the for loop ends, the execution goes to the last line of the queen() function and then again goes to the starting of for loop. When the for loop ends, recursion isn't taking place. How is this possible?

Comment: _"How is this possible?"_ This is called recursion.

Comment: [See recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#In_computer_science).

Comment: `queen(row+1,n);` : You are calling the `queen` function inside the `queen` function. It's called recursion.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but when column=n, the for loop ends. It doesn't call queen(row+1,n)

Comment: queen() function will not be called when column=n+1. No one is getting what I'm saying

Comment: @Savithru when column=n+1, how will queen(row+1,n) be called?

Comment: @WhozCraig please see my question carefully

Comment: @WhozCraig To be more specific, how does this code prints ALL the solutions for the n-queen problem? Suppose I give n=8, it prints 92 chessboard arrangements.
According to the algorithm used here, shouldn't the program stop after printing one solution?

Comment: @PriyaChand So, your actual question is why doesn't this stop and print **a** solution rather than continuing to the next solution? Once you find a solution you print it, but you're still in a recursive stack of activation calls, each of which is mid-loop in partial proposed solutions. Those loops continue when their activation pops up, and the process continues to the next solution. In short, `queen` makes no information conveyance back up the recursion stack (by way of return value, global, whatever) that a solution has been found and all those loops can just terminate. So they continue.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for looking into it but I still couldn't understand. 
What my doubt actually is:
1. main() function calls queen() function
2. queen() function has a lot of recursions but finally it ends after the *column* variable reaches the value n+1

But the queen function doesn't end, it just goes on and on and on

Comment: @PriyaChand remember that when you say "after the column variable reaches the value `n+1`" you're only looking at *that* inner most iteration. There are still recursive calls drilled in on the activation stack that are *not* at `n+1` yet, Because there is no quick-exit via something like a return value of `queen` (currently unused) or some other mechanism of conveying a solution was found, all loops will march on. Run your debugger, put a breakpoint on the `print` call in your `queen` function, then look at the call stack each time it's called, noting the arguments. It should become clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of recursion. You are calling queen(row+1,n) and this takes the control to the starting of the function.

Comment: The OP knows that. The question is why does it *appear* to continue to do that even when the final loop reaches it's control limit and break.

Comment: When the column variable's value reaches n and the for loop ends, queen(row+1,n) is not called

Comment: I also tried debugging and this is happening just because of recursion every time when you are calling queen function the for loop will run till is breaks and once it breaks the previous function call is running which starts the loop again from start

Comment: @yogijain Your last comment is actually the answer the OP is looking for, whether they  comprehend it or not is another matter.